# Helm installation

Tags: dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install helm using Dockerfile. I have tried following methods:

1.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install apt-transport-https
RUN curl -s https://helm.baltorepo.com/organization/signing.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian/ all main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/helm-stable-debian.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install helm
```

2. RUN curl -o helm-v2.10.0-linux-amd64.tgz https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.10.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar -zxvf helm-v2.10.0-linux-amd64.tgz && mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm

Both of them are returning `helm not found` when I do `helm -h`.

Comment: What's your higher-level goal by doing this?  Usually to use Helm you need both deployment code (the chart) and user credentials to access Kubernetes, so it'll be kind of inconvenient to drive it via Docker.

Comment: I need to run the code in the docker containers. If we do this step, everytime I start the deployment my VM will have this pre-installed. I do not need to add installation for every single repo/code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try.

Download the binary

`curl -OL https://get.helm.sh/helm-version-linux-arm64.tar.gz`

Unpack it
`tar -zxvf your_dowloaded_file`

Find unpacked binary and move it to desired destination
`mv directory/helm /usr/local/bin/helm`

You can find helm binary releases [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases)

You can find other installation method [here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/#from-the-binary-releases)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the HELM_HOME env var.  That was it...it worked.

```
ENV HELM_HOME /helm
```

Plain old `HELM_HOME` does not appear in the [Helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/), but looks like `HOME_CONFIG_HOME`, `HELM_DATA_HOME`, and `HELM_CACHE_HOME` can be used for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
RUN apt install wget \ 
&& wget https://baltocdn.com/helm/signing.asc \
&& apt-key add signing.asc \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install apt-transport-https \
&& echo "deb https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian/ all main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/helm-stable-debian.list \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install helm
```